# Convert timestamp/date time from UTC to EST Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime-format

I have a field with a date/time value like this:

```
2009-11-17 18:40:05
```

It's in UTC. In the query how can I convert this to EST?

I'm trying something like this but it throws an error.

```
// datetime is the field name
SELECT 
   FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP TO_DATE(datetime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24miss'), 'EST') AS DT
FROM
   db_name
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had to tweak it slightly to get it to work on my database, but this worked:

```
select from_tz(to_timestamp('2009-11-17 18:40:05','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC') 
at time zone 'America/New_York' from dual
```

The key is the "at time zone" syntax.

Comment: Thanks I just found that the date was in the wrong format, Duh :)

Comment: What's that "TIMEZONE TO_DATE(...)" syntax? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Specifying timestamp literals is easier with the ANSI syntax, so you could replace "to_timestamp('2009-11-17 18:40:05','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')" with "timestamp '2009-11-17 18:40:05'" ... a little more compact

Comment: does this takes into account of daylight savings?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to convert a date field from UTC to EST, this worked for me:

```
CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(DATE_FIELD AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') 
at time zone 'America/New_York' AS Date) as DESIRED_FIELD_NAME
```

First, I cast the desired date field (as DATE_FIELD) to a timestamp.  The result of the cast is the first parameter of the FROM_TZ function, which requires the parameter to be of type TIMESTAMP.  The second parameter is 'UTC', since that is what we are changing from.

Then, I cast the results of that function call back to type DATE and give it an alias.

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(systimestamp at time zone 'EST','HH') EST_TIME,
    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH') EDT_TIME,
    NEW_TIME(SYSDATE,
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN to_char(systimestamp at time zone 'EST','HH') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH') 
                THEN 'EST'
                ELSE 'EDT'
            END
        ),'GMT') 
    from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ORACLE, I am using 12.2.0.1.0 64bit

```
SELECT * FROM v$version; --find version information
SELECT SYSDATE UTC, NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'EST') EST FROM DUAL; --will give both zones
```

This worked for me, should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach to get the date and time can be,

```
from_tz(CAST(DATE_FIELD AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') at time zone 'America/New_York' as DESIRED_FIELD_NAME
```