# How to parse a string to a date, when the string has a character in it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to parse `2015-07-09T12:22:29` using `TO_DATE` using the following date format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS`, but I'm getting back the message as the date format is not recognized.

Comment: [Documentaion link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51078) to back up Andy Lester's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the `T` in double quotes, like `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS`.

```
select to_date( '2015-07-09T12:22:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS' ) from dual;

TO_DATE('
---------
09-JUL-15
```

Here's the [relevant documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51078).  (Thanks Alex)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the "T" in your date string indicates that it is in UTC format, not as standard date. Just ignoring the "T" character is not going to result in a correct datetime value, as you are not accounting for your local timezone.

Check out this post for some additional information:

[Convert timestamp/date time from UTC to EST Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751075/convert-timestamp-date-time-from-utc-to-est-oracle-sql)