# Need format mask

Tags: oracle, to-date

I am getting format string not recognized.

Date we are getting from source : `2015-11-15 02:22:11.000 GMT`

Can anyone help me with proper mask for this to convert in `TO_DATE(date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR')`

Need output in `15/11/2014 2:22:00 AM`

Comment: Hi Karthik, Welcome to stackoverflow, please posts your attempts to solve this question and mainly search in stack overflow for duplicate of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp/date time from UTC to EST Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751075/convert-timestamp-date-time-from-utc-to-est-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use fractions of second or timezone region in format mask in TO_DATE function, you have to use TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ and then convert it to desired format.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2015-11-15 02:22:11.000 GMT', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR'), 'MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY fmHHfm:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL
```